# Class Normalizer not found (in PHP 5.3.8)

Tags: php, pecl, intl

I'm receiving this PHP error while trying to use the `Normalizer` class, specifically the `Normalizer::normalize` function:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Normalizer' not found.
```

I'm currently using PHP 5.3.8 so, according to the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/normalizer.normalize.php), it should be activated by default. The only thing I can think about is a problem with the PECL intl extension.

I checked in the `php/ext/` folder and the `php_intl.dll` is there. I checked the `php.ini` file, and there was no `extension=php_intl.dll` command, so I added it. But still no luck. Beyond that I have no idea. Can anybody please tell me what the hell is going on here?

Thanks

Additional info: When I run `phpinfo`, there is **no** mention about the PECL intl extension, so I'm guessing it's wasn't properly installed.

### What solved my problem:

http://www.tiv.net/2010/12/php-intl-extension-windows-apache.html, uninstalling XAMPP 1.77 (which has some kind of internal bug with the PECL intl extension) and installing XAMPP 1.73.

Comment: Are you running apache (or another http server) ? have you restarted it ?

Comment: Yes, and in Xampp (for Windows). I restarted it and nothing changed :/

Comment: did you read http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.extensions.php where other extensions are stored on your machine ?

Comment: Did you tried to enable intl extension in xampp panel (I suspect that there should be some admin panel :)) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quote from http://pecl.php.net/package/intl:

> The Internationalization extension exposes functionality of the ICU
>   library to PHP.
>
> All the binaries depend on the ICU libraries (version 4.8), which
>   must be available to PHP.

just download and extract the content of the zip with ICU libraries in the folder where php.exe is and it will work

ps:  the php_intl.dll can be downloaded from the same location (in the description where is says "Windows binaries" :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, too bad I'm using a paid hosting now and I don't have that kind of access :/. Good to know anyways

Answer (score 7):

If you are on ubuntu:

```
sudo apt install php-intl
```

Comment: Was hopeful this would do it for me on a fresh Ubuntu 21.10 laptop but it simply says php-intl is already installed.Thoughts? I get that Class 'Normalizer' not found when I try to do anything with Composer (v. 2.0.9)

Answer (score 2):

Left-click on the WAMP tray icon, go to PHP, go to PHP extensions and check php_intl. Than restart the server.

Because WAMP(server) uses another settings file everything looks fine while it doesn't.

Comment: Thanks, I was using XAMPP not WAMP though, so it wasn't of too much help.

Comment: clearly written for XAMPP not WAMP, first read question then answer that